# Is there a way to host WCF service that uses web sockets in the SharePoint context?

Tags: 2013, web-services, wcf

Sorry for a broad and poorly formulated question. I've been thinking about hosting a WCF service inside a SharePoint context (ISAPI folder) that uses web sockets. Did someone manage to accomplish it? Is there an example I can have a look at?

At the moment we are using node server for it, but I want to move everything to the SharePoint project to simplify and automate deployment process.

Would you recommend using SignalR instead?